# How to include a vector with multiple elements in a paste() statement?

Tags: r, rstudio-server

Have a character vector  called error.list with multiple elements in it.  I tried to include the complete vector in my paste statement as shown below:

```
paste("Hi, Your data has the following errors:", error.list," Regards, XYZ", 
sep='').
```

But I am getting an error. The console says it can't add all the elements in a single paste statement. Can help me with this? is there another way to do it?

Comment: paste(c("Hi, Your data has the following errors:", error.list, " Regards, XYZ"), sep = " ") like this ?

Comment: This code works for me `error.list <- c("a","b")` (albeit the period at the end of your code). You need to make your issue reproducible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Concatenate Strings](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/paste.html)

**Your approach will work `For inputs of length 1` but you have a vector.**

> Because `error.list` is a `vector`, use one of the following methods:

```
error.list <- c("a", "b", "c")

paste(c("Hi, Your data has the following errors:", error.list, " Regards, XYZ"), sep = " ")
```

> Provide the output:
>
> ```
> [1] "Hi, Your data has the following errors:" "a"                                      
> [3] "b"                                       "c"                                      
> [5] " Regards, XYZ"
> ```

One line use parameter `collapse =`  :

```
paste(c("Hi, Your data has the following errors:", error.list, " Regards, XYZ"), sep = "  ", collapse = " ")
```

> Provide the output:
>
> ```
> "Hi, Your data has the following errors: a b c  Regards, XYZ"
> ```

---

> or you can use `paste0()` with parameter `collapse =` to get one line output, for also using the `error.list` as vector:

```
paste0(c("Hi, Your data has the following errors:", error.list, " Regards, XYZ"), collapse = " ")
```

> Provide the output:
>
> `[1] "Hi, Your data has the following errors: a b c  Regards, XYZ"`